# what's the relationship between npm packages angular-cli and @angular/cli?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

What's the relationship between npm packages angular-cli and @angular/cli? https://cli.angular.io/ refers to @angular/cli in its documentation.  Is angular-cli simply a previous version of the CLI which is hosted for support reasons?  Or is angular-cli simply an alias which now redirects to @angular/cli?

Answer (score 2):

You can figureout that yourself by simply running

```
npm show angular-cli version
```

and

```
npm show @angular/cli version
```

this way you can see that version `1.0.0-beta.28.3` of `angular-cli` was the latest that way back if you compare that with the `@angular/cli` latest version.

Also if you scroll down at https://github.com/angular/angular-cli to `Updating Angular CLI` section:

> If you're using Angular CLI 1.0.0-beta.28 or less, you need to
>   uninstall angular-cli package. It should be done due to changing of
>   package's name and scope from angular-cli to @angular/cli:

```
npm uninstall -g angular-cli
npm uninstall --save-dev angular-cli
```

To install the latest one

```
npm cache clean
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

To check your cli version run `ng -v`

Answer (score 0):

On NPM, packages can be published by an organisation, which groups the packages and lets you have some confidence in the source.

The `@angular` part of the package name denotes the Angular organisation on NPM. I would take an educated guess that they may have previously added their packages before creating the organisation and publishing the packages there.

In this case, I recommend that you use the packages from the `@angular` organisation.

Comment: thanks fenton.  I'm guessing that npm introduced the concept of @organization labeling after the angular team published the initial cli?

Comment: Yes, but it's all the rage these days :)

Answer (score 0):

**angular-cli** is Angular CLI of version 1.0.0-beta.28 or less.

Then they [had changed](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/pull/4328) package's name and scope from angular-cli to **@angular/cli**

So prefer installing @angular/cli as it is current package name

Answer (score 0):

packages `angular-cli` is deprecated and no longer valid. When angular team started they created this one but in future they moved it to `@angular/cli`.

So don't use angular-cli as its old and not updated and may be hold error full code.

And just use `@angular/cli` as it points to angular 4.x.x which is latest and keep updated by the angular team.